# PHP: preg_match function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, regex, preg-match

I need to test if a string matches following ruby regular expression:

```
/^[0-9]*[\u007C-]{1}[0-9]*$/
```

My problem here is, that I am not using PHP, I am using JavaScript... I saw some examples as i searched through google, but i don't get it.
Hopefully someone can help me!

Comment: Can you tell what exactly are you trying to search? So that we can construct something in JavaScript?

Comment: Why do you need the unicode representation of the simple ascii character `|`?

Comment: @PraveenKumar The user is sending some kind of token as a packet to a node js server through websocket, the js server is encoding it and at the end you get a string. I want to check if the string matches the given requirements i set through the regular expression

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte How else are you going to represent a symbol? That needs escaping. Except when it doesn't, like in a character class. Oof...

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I didn't find a different solution, because if you just wrote the | character, php would recognize it as an 'or' operator...

Comment: No. `|` inside a character class would always be a literal `|` in any regex flavor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function isMatch(str) {
  return /^[0-9]*[\u007C-]{1}[0-9]*$/.test(str)
}

console.log(isMatch('|'))
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options:

`'some string'.match(/^[0-9]*[\u007C-]{1}[0-9]*$/)`

`/^[0-9]*[\u007C-]{1}[0-9]*$/.test('a string')`

I'm not too familiar with the syntax of Ruby regular expressions, so you might need to adapt the syntax a bit:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions